# sum of binomial with normal distribution estimation

Tags: bayesian, estimation

Let
$$Y=X+V$$
where $X$ and $V$ are independent random variables, $V$ is Gaussian with mean zero and
variance unity, and $X$ takes the values $\pm 1$ with equal probability. Show that $X = \tanh(Y)$.

Comment: The conclusion is false, as $Y$ can take infinitely many values but $X$ can only take two values.

Comment: Something along the lines of $P(X=+1)=\tanh Y$  is true, from the relationship between logistic regression and linear discrimination. It might be worth asking a new question with the right question in it.

Comment: $X$ actually has a marginal Rademacher distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- What you are trying to prove is $\mathbb P(X=+1 \mid Y)=\frac12(1+\tanh Y)$ and $\mathbb P(X=-1 \mid Y)=\frac12(1-\tanh Y)$
- With a slight abuse of notation, $$\mathbb P(X=+1 \mid Y) = \frac{p(X=+1, Y=y)}{p(Y=y)} \\= \frac{p(X=+1, Y=y)}{p(X=+1, Y=y)+ p(X=-1, Y=y)}$$
- where $p(X=+1, Y=y)=p(Y=y \mid X=+1)\mathbb P(X=+1) $ $= p(V=y-1)\mathbb P(X=+1)$ etc.
- and $V\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ while $\mathbb P(X=+1)=\mathbb P(X=-1)=\frac12$